# $f:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ odd $\Rightarrow$ $\mathrm{deg}(f)$ odd (Borsuk-Ulam theorem)

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of Borsuk-Ulam theorem ($n=2$) that we did in our class. The only problematic part is the last sentence in the proof of lemma 1.

$\mathbb{S}^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. We know that $\mathrm{deg}:\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathrm{deg}([\alpha]):=\tilde{\alpha}(1)$, is an isomorphism, where $\tilde{\alpha}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the unique *lifting* of the loop $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$, i.e. $p\circ\tilde{\alpha}=\alpha$, where $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$, $p(t)=e^{2\pi it}$.

[image]

**Lemma 1:** continuous $f:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ odd (i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$) $\Longrightarrow$ $\mathrm{deg}(f)\in\mathbb{Z}$ odd.

**Proof:** Without loss of generality: $f(1)=1$ (if not, then we compose $f$ with a rotation; the degree and odd-ness is preserved). If $q:I\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$, $q(t):=e^{2\pi i t}$, then $q(t+1/2)=-q(t)$. Now $f\circ q:I\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ is a loop at $1$, $\widetilde{f\circ q}$ its lifting, and $\mathrm{deg}(f)=\widetilde{f\circ q}(1)$. Clearly $p\circ\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)=f\circ q(1/2)=-1$, so by the definition of $p$, we have $\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)=k+1/2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. (So far, I understand everything; here is what troubles me.) Since $f$ is odd, we have $\widetilde{f\circ q}(1)=k+1/2+k+1/2=2k+1$. **WHY?**

**Lemma 2:** continuous $f:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S^1}$ is not odd.

**Proof:** $\mathbb{S^1}\overset{i}{\hookrightarrow}\mathbb{S}^2\overset{f}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{S^1}$. If $f$ is odd, then so is $f\circ i$. By Lemma 1, $f\circ i$ has odd degree, so it isn't nullhomotopic. But since $i$ is not surjective, it is nullhomotopic, hence so is $f\circ i$, $\rightarrow\leftarrow$. $\blacksquare$

**Theorem (Borsuk-Ulam, $n=2$):** $\forall$ continuous $f:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ $\exists x\in\mathbb{S}^2$: $f(-x)=f(x)$.

**Proof:** If the theorem were not true, then $F(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{\|f(x)-f(-x)\|}$, would be a well defined continuous odd map $\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$, $\rightarrow\leftarrow$ (Lemma 2). $\blacksquare$

Comment: When you say "$\widetilde{f \circ q}$ its lifting", what exactly do you know about it? Well, $\widetilde{f \circ q}(x+1) = \widetilde{f \circ q}(x) + \operatorname{deg}(f)$ for all $x$ and $\widetilde{f \circ q}(0) = 0$. Now, can you say what $\widetilde{f \circ q}(-1/2)$ is?

Comment: $\widetilde{f\circ q}$ is defined on $I$ and $-1/2\notin I$, so I'm a little confused. Additionally, where did you get $\widetilde{f\circ q}(x+1)=\widetilde{f\circ q}(x)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(1)$?

Comment: Okay, let me try to explain it differently I misunderstood you somewhat. Forget what I said before. You haven't really used "oddness" yet: The lifting from $0$ to $1/2$ is "essentially the same" as the lifting from $1/2$ to $1$, just rotated halfways. That is: you start at $k +1/2$ and circle up or down along the spiral exactly the same way as before and that's because of oddness.

Comment: OK, this is just $f\circ q(t+1/2)=-f\circ q(t)$. But why do we have $\widetilde{f\circ q}(1)=\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)$?

Comment: Yes, that's true. But the first thing you say (oddness) means that you're doing the same thing twice. You're moving along a certain trajectory on the spiral, until you get to the parameter $1/2$ and land at $k + 1/2$ on the spiral. Then you're just making *exactly the same movement* once again, just rotated halfway, starting from $k + 1/2$ in the picture, until you get to the parameter $1$ and land at $k+1/2+k+1/2$. Therefore $\widetilde{f\circ q}(1)=\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)$. I wish I could just show you by pointing in the picture.

Comment: Hmm, are you saying $\widetilde{f\circ q}$ is also odd? Or are you saying that $\widetilde{f\circ q}(t+1/2)=-\widetilde{f\circ q}(t)$? I'm a little confused. Could you use some equations, that'll maybe help me. Also, I've edited the picture.

Comment: Here's what Theo is saying in a bit more formulaic way: you can prove (using crucially this particular covering projection) that $\tilde{f}\circ q(1/2+t)$ and $\tilde{f}\circ q(1/2)+\tilde{f}\circ q(t)$ are lifts of the same map with the same starting point, so they must be equal.

Comment: @Miha: thanks man. O, how I wonder who you are...

Comment: why is "$i$ is not surjective so $f\circ i$ is not surjective" true??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I corrected the argument, see the edited post. Thanks for your remark!

Comment: @Leon This seems reasonable :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out, using the comment of Miha.

It is enough to prove $\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2+t)=\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(t)$, since $t:=1/2$ gives the desired formula.

In general, for a given $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$, $\alpha:\partial I\mapsto1$, by the definition and uniqueness of liftings, if $\beta:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\beta:0\mapsto0$, and $p\circ\beta=\alpha$, then $\beta=\widetilde{\alpha}$.

In our case, $\alpha:=f\circ q(1/2+t)$ and $\beta:=\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(t)$. We have
$$\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(0)=(k+1/2)+0=\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2+0)$$ 
and 
$$p\big(\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)+\widetilde{f\circ q}(t)\big)=e^{2\pi i ...}=p(\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2))\cdot p(\widetilde{f\circ q}(t))$$
$$=-1\cdot f\circ q(t)=f(-q(t))=f\circ q(1/2+t),$$
which proves the claim.

Intuitively, when $t$ moves from $0$ to $1/2$, $q(t)$ moves in the upper half of the circle, $f\circ q(t)$ wraps around $\mathbb{S}^1$, and $\widetilde{f\circ q}(t)$ moves up and down on the spiral $\mathbb{R}$. But when $t$ moves from $1/2$ to $1$, $q(t)$ moves in the lower half of the circle, on which $f$ has the same values as on the upper half ($f(-x)=-f(x)$), so $f\circ q(t)$ is the same, and therefore the lift $\widetilde{f\circ q}(t)$ is also the same, just translated in $\mathbb{R}$ by $\widetilde{f\circ q}(1/2)$.

Comment: That's the argument I had in mind but I was too lazy to spell it out :) Sorry that my comments seemed to have confused you more than they have helped.

Comment: @Theo: No problem, as long as it's solved in the end.

Answer (score 6):

To keep more to formulas, consider the following: As you already pointed out, by the lifting property there is a unique continuous function $q: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that 
$$f(e^{2\pi i t}) = e^{2\pi i q(t)}$$

Since $f$ is odd we have $$e^{2\pi i q(t+1/2)} = f(e^{2\pi i (t+1/2)}) = f(-e^{2\pi it}) = - f(e^{2\pi it}) = e^{2\pi i (q(t)+1/2)}$$ so

$$q(t+1/2) \equiv q(t) + 1/2 \pmod {\mathbb Z}$$

Therefore the continuous function $t \mapsto q(t+1/2) - q(t) - 1/2$ only takes values in $\mathbb Z$ and thus has to be constant.
So there is $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n = q(t+1/2) - q(t) - 1/2$ for all $t$.

Now

\begin{align*}\deg(f) &= q(1) - q(0)\\ &= [q(1) - q(1/2) - 1/2] + [q(1/2) - q(0) - 1/2] + 1 \\ &= 2n + 1\end{align*}

and we are done. Maybe you can find out what you've been missing by comparing this to your version of the proof (they are both more or less the same).

Comment: I don't understand your very first sentence. The map $q$, as I defined it, maps $q:I\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$. Moreover, the **lifting property** in our case states: for $f\circ q:I\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ there exists unique $\widetilde{f\circ q}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $p\circ\widetilde{f\circ q}=f\circ q$. I don't understand your proof.

Comment: @Leon: My $q$ is not your $q$ (should probalby have called it differently). It is rather the lifting of $f(e^{2\pi it})$. To your second question: When you know that a unique lifting exists for any closed interval $I$, it is not difficult to then also show that a unique lifting exists when we take the whole real line as our domain - think of it as a generalized lifting property.